# How do I respresent the system under development in a UML use case?

Tags: java, uml

Using UML2.0 Case Diagrams, what is the normal way to indicate in the diagram that the "system is under development"?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a stereotype for this or one for each phase/timebox/sprint.  In the past I've used the **system** scope box to indicate a similar difference between the existing system, the two proposed phases of development.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Simply you put notes on a diagram:

[image]

Or  can use "sterotypes"

[image]

Or even can use "Colors"

[image]

> But for me "to keep track of project" status on diagram is not a good
>   idea. You will have to update it.
>
> So keep the track of project "on" an other place...Why not keep track
>   of project on a simple kanban board:

[image]